# How to output sed result in sed itself?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to create a tool it replace bash sources by the content of it with sed command.

For example :

```bash
# hello.txt

Hello
```

```bash
# bash script

source ./hello
```

to

```bash
# bash script

Hello
```

I tried like this :

```bash
# compiler

sed 's|source \(\.\/.*\)|'$(cat '\1')'|g' $1 > ./test
```

Where $1 is the command argument : `compiler ./filetocompile`

I want to use the result of sed capture (path of the file in source) to replace the line with the file content, and send the result to another file (test file in this case)

But the result is only blank lines, or carriage returns, not the content of source file.

What am I doing wrong?

(Sorry if my english is bad, I'm learning it)

Comment: `$(cat '\1')` is be executed before `sed`, and since you most likely don't have a file with name `\1`, it returns empty string (into stdout), and you substituting `source` lines with said empty string.

Comment: You can attempt to solve your task with splitting steps: 1. grep file for list of `source` invocations, 2. loop through said list and substitute files one-by-one. But this solutions has a couple of problems: it is prone to infinite loops, it will substitute later files into former once (if they have `source` invocations).

Comment: What should happen if the file being sourced itself sources a 3rd file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `compiler` file should work:

```bash
# compiler

sed 's|source \(\.\/.*\)|cat \1|e' $1 > ./test
```

For example, if you have a file `text` like this:

```bash
Hello
```

A file `filetocompile` like this:

```bash
# bash script

source ./hello
```

Then running `compiler ./filetocompile` should produces a file `test` like this:

```bash
# bash script

Hello
```

The compiler works by using the `e` flag after the substitution command in `sed`:

- The substitution itself converts the match into a `cat <whatever was after source>` command.
- If the substitution succeeds, the `e` flag runs the line in a shell and replaces it with the result.

The problem with your `compiler` file is that the section `$(cat '\1')` runs in a subshell before the sed command . That is akin to running `cat \1` directly in a shell, where the string `\1` doesn't have the special meaning it would have inside a `sed` substitution command.

**Note:** There's always a risk that the resulting file ends up in an invalid state, depending on the context of the `source` command and the contents of the file being sourced. Verify that the resulting script looks good before running, and consider other solutions if you need something more robust, depending on your use case and specific context.

Comment: Many thanks for solution and explanations, it works perfectly now !
I'll improve this tool later.